# how to inser dash(-) between the given number but i want to enter in between even numbers

Tags: javascript

```
The program seems like this it is nice but it jumps between 4 and 6 I have not to get the idea?
if anyone sole this.
     **I want to enter dash between the given consecutive even numbers..** * but in my testing, I jump the even number*
```

**when I check my code is correct but there there is one error I jump my first even numbers **
`

```
function convertNumber(num) {
        let arr = num.toString().split('').map(Number);
        for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
            let check = arr[i];
            let check2 = arr[i + 1]
            // console.log(check);
            if (check % 2 == 0) {
                console.log(check);
                if (check2 % 2 == 0) {
                    arr.splice(check, 0, "-");
                    // console.log(arr);
                }
                // console.log(check);
                // console.log(-1);
            }
        }
        console.log(arr);
        // console.log(typeof (arr));
    }
    convertNumber(025468)
```

;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function convertNumber(num) {
        let arr = [];
        const str = num.toString();

        for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
          arr.push(Number(str[i]))
          if (Number(str[i]) % 2 === 0 && Number(str[i + 1]) % 2 === 0) {
            arr.push('-');
          }
        }
        console.log(arr);
        // console.log(typeof (arr));
    }
    convertNumber(025468)
```

Comment: but, what about in between 0 and 2 how to do it b/c the two are even

Comment: The issue is with the leading zero.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get `[2, 5, 4, '-', 6, '-', 8]`?

You should create a new array and push elements in there. I recommend against doing `splice` on the array on which you are looping. Rule of thumb, don't change the array where you do the for loop.

```
function convertNumber(num) {
  let newArr = [];
  let arr = num.toString().split("").map(Number);
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    let check = arr[i];
    let check2 = arr[i + 1];
    // console.log(check);
    if (check % 2 == 0) {
      console.log(check);
      newArr.push(check);
      if (check2 % 2 == 0) {
        newArr.push("-");
        // console.log(arr);
      }
      // console.log(check);
      // console.log(-1);
    }
  }
  console.log(newArr);
  // console.log(typeof (arr));
  return newArr;
}

convertNumber(025468);
```

Note: I added `return newArr`